# How can I plot the difference between marginal effects for a categorical variable?

Tags: r, plot, ordinal, emmeans

I'm trying to plot the difference between marginal effects for a dependent categorical variable. I have tried using emmeans, but I can't get what I want.

I'll try to follow the example in [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/sophisticated.html) for emmeans for ordinal models.

I run this model with interaction:

```r
library(ordinal)
library(emmeans)
wine.clm <- clm(rating ~ temp * contact, data = wine)
```

Then I plot the model:

```r
plot_model(wine.clm, type = "pred",
           terms = c("contact", "temp"))
```

This isn't bad. But to simplify, I want to plot the difference between the predicted probabilities for warm and cold. This, I hope, should also highlight the interaction.

I've tried with emmeans, which gives me a difference, but only for the odd-logs latent variable.

```r
emmeans(wine.clm, list(pairwise ~ contact|temp))
```

Instead, I would like to plot the difference in probabilities for each rating category .

Comment: Where is this 'wine' data set? It will help us to understand, reproduce and resolve your problem if we can work from the same data set as you.

Comment: The 'wine' data comes with the 'ordinal' package, which also includes 'clm'. I have roughly followed the 'ordinal models' section in the vignette: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/sophisticated.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use [the `marginaleffects` package](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/) (disclaimer: I am the author).

See [the Contrasts vignette for different ways to compare predicted probabilities.](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/contrasts.html) Here’s one possibility:

```r
library(ordinal)
library(ggplot2)
library(marginaleffects)

wine.clm <- clm(rating ~ temp * contact, data = wine)

cmp <- comparisons(wine.clm,
    variables = "temp",
    newdata = datagrid(contact = unique))

ggplot(cmp, aes(x = contact, y = comparison, ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high)) +
    geom_pointrange() +
    facet_wrap(~group) +
    labs(x = "Contact", y = "P(Y|Warm) - P(Y|Cold)")
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. A small issue: when I run   cmp <- comparisons(wine.clm,
    variables = "temp",
    newdata = datagrid(contact = unique))  the variable contact turns into rowid with values 1 and 2 instead of 'no' and 'yes'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `rowid` is a column which is mainly used for "accounting" purposes internally by the package. It is useful for users when `newdata` is the original dataset, because then it allows you to ask: "How different are predicted probability for an individual like the one in the first row of my data." In this case, when using `datagrid()`, the `rowid` column doesn't serve much of a purpose and can be ignored. As you can see in the `contrast` column, we are looking at the change in predicted Pr when `temp` is "warm" vs. "cold", and the `contact` column gives you the value of control/moderator variable.

Comment: when I try this the `cmp` file does not contain `contact`. I can rename `rowid`, but I would like to get your result.

Comment: Can you try to (a) install the dev version from Github, (b) restart your R session completely, (c) try again? `remotes::install_github("vincentarelbundock/marginaleffects")`

Comment: I have now installed the development version instead of the CRAN release. It works fine. Many thanks.